# Error in checking out multiple repository from azure devops using git clone command

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, git-clone

I am on classic Azure DevOps(not yaml). I read to use `git clone` command to check out the second repository in my 2nd phase of the build. When I am doing that I am getting this error which has no description. I see code is available in the folder, but still, the error is there. So, not sure if everything happened fine.

```
git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" https://abc.visualstudio.com/Aq/_git/CodeRepo --verbose
```

[image]

These is the command I created
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me -
I created a PowerShell command for this in my classic pipeline

```
$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'
git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" https://abc.visualstudio.com/Aq/_git/CodeRepo
```